# Unable to merge features in KML with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, kml, merge

I am 100% new to QGIS and I'm having issues to do something that seems easy; delete some lines of polygons so I merge them.

I select regions with *Select Features by Polygon* but all edit options are disabled.

[image]

Data is from a KML file, it can be found at [Polygonen NL Postcodes 4PP](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?snapid=S16026080vay)

This is the code of one of the polygons:

```
<Placemark>
    <snippet></snippet>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[<div class="googft-info-window">
        <b>PC4CODE:</b> 3584
        </div>]]>
    </description>
    <styleUrl>#Style0-polygon-3-map</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name='PC4CODE'>
            <value>3584</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    5.195259,52.077105,0.0 5.19297,52.07784,0.0 5.184979,52.076905,0.0 5.182108,52.076264,0.0 5.179659,52.078167,0.0 5.175612,52.0783,0.0 5.173373,52.079515,0.0 5.168691,52.077182,0.0 5.167285,52.076597,0.0 5.163053,52.07819,0.0 5.161547,52.07969,0.0 5.159449,52.080566,0.0 5.156781,52.080794,0.0 5.153706,52.080326,0.0 5.147651,52.07711,0.0 5.144558,52.076654,0.0 5.141332,52.076851,0.0 5.141845,52.078563,0.0 5.144388,52.081649,0.0 5.147358,52.084668,0.0 5.148194,52.086306,0.0 5.147915,52.088275,0.0 5.146056,52.090319,0.0 5.144159,52.096222,0.0 5.156885,52.09852,0.0 5.161309,52.094512,0.0 5.166102,52.093676,0.0 5.168183,52.094002,0.0 5.170324,52.094185,0.0 5.174459,52.093687,0.0 5.179074,52.093366,0.0 5.179679,52.09462,0.0 5.182451,52.09443,0.0 5.18439,52.093213,0.0 5.185912,52.093285,0.0 5.189662,52.08635,0.0 5.192716,52.085956,0.0 5.195259,52.077105,0.0
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

Does it have anything that make impossible to merge polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the XML-based data format (KML). See http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html for more information.

Workaround:

- Save the data as GeoPackage.
- Start editing.
- Make selection.
- Merge.
- Stop editing and save edits.
- Save as KML.